# Twilio SMS - How to prevent further replies?

Tags: twilio

I made a simple chatbot using the studio template and it works fine. However, it then loops after the last response. So let's say I give the user 2 choices, Y and N. After they say Y they get a response but if they message the bot again they get the initial message once again to loop the process. How do I stop this? In the docs I only found info on how to stop all incoming messages but this isn't what I want. I just want to end the convo for good as in my application it has a one time use intention. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's not really a way to stop incoming texts. What you want to do in this case is stop responding to an incoming text after the initial flow through.

The way to do this would be to use [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/runtime/functions) and function widgets to store the numbers that have successfully completed the questions (you could use any database for this, if you want to keep it within Twilio then [Twilio Sync](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync) can help here). Then you can insert a function widget at the start of the flow that retrieves whether the number messaging has completed the questions and combine with a split widget to decide whether to send the first message or just complete the flow.

Let me know if that helps at all.